# Why Doesn't Knex Use Table Column Names on the Resulting Row Objects?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm making a query with Knex (PostgreSQL):

```
knex('foos')
  .select(columnsThatAreAMixOfFooAndBarColumns)
  .leftJoin('bars', 'foos.bar_id', 'bars.id')
  .where({ 'foos.id': id })
```

When I get back results, I *don't* get back `[{foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2, ...`.  Instead I get back `[{ id: 1, ...`.

What's so bizzare is that Knex is building the right query: if I log it I'll see `SELECT "foos"."id", "bars"."id", ...`.  But for some strange reason I can't figure out, Knex decides to merge all the resulting columns together, so I lose `bars.id` entirely and `foos.id` gets renamed to `id`.

Can anyone explain what's going on, and how I can fix it?  I've tried adding `returning`, using `columns` instead of `select`, and otherwise changing how I make the query, but it doesn't help, and again the query Knex builds isn't the problem: it's the results.

**EDIT:** I re-ran the same exact query using `knex.raw(query)` instead ... and got the exact same (`id`, not `foos_id`) result.  So it's definitely not how the query is made that's the problem: I'm somehow doing something to make Knex build the results in a way that ignores the qualified column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell (and it's difficult because the documentation is almost exclusively about query *building*, with almost nothing about the results) the answer is "this is just how Knex works".  It seems like it would make more sense to have the library return the qualified names, but for whatever reason it doesn't.

Instead, if you want to JOIN tables in Knex, it seems that you *have* to alias (ie. `foos.id AS foos_id`) every column that shares a name :(

Comment: That is just how DB driver returns joined columns. So knex is not re-documenting what kind of results database / database driver is returning (well there are some exceptions, but mostly knex doesn't care nor document it).

Comment: But in my example, it's not like Postgres returns results in the form `[{ id: ...` and MySQL returns `[{ 'foo.id': ...`.  The format of the results is consistent throughout Knex regardless of the driver ... no?

Comment: Yes, results are usually pretty consistent between drivers and all of them returns column names from join *without* table prefixes (I suppose that comes from SQL standard). So it is requirement of SQL language that one has to add `select joined_table.col1 as co1_alias` to get overlapping column names with different prefix. Some drivers indeed makes it possible to return query results as an array instead of map, which makes it possible to get same column name multiple times in result, but knex still wouldn't have any idea of which result column name belongs to which table.

Comment: But Knex knows *exactly* which columns I selected in the first place, and what order I selected them in.  If I select `a.b, b.c`, it doesn't matter if the driver returns an array of result row arrays with no column headers whatsoever ... Knex already knows that `resultsRow[0]` is `a.b`, and `resultsRow[1]` is `b.c`.  Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems completely irrelevant what the driver returns, as long as Knex has the SELECT clause.

Comment: Yep, you are missing something. The way how DB drivers are returning responses to knex. By default drivers doesn't return each row as an array, but as an object. So if you select `a.b` and `b.c` driver returns `{b: val1, c: val2}`. There is no mapping between an index and column name listed in `.select()`. Also it would fail for example with `.select('a.*','b.id','c.*' )` probably in some other cases too. Though you could try to use DB driver in a mode where it returns rows as an arrays instead of an object if you like to. Some drivers has an option for that.